# Embarrasingly I can't get a div to pick up a background colour

Tags: html, css

What I would like is to have the iframe cover 90% of the screen and add some buttons at the bottom, I need a background color on the div that covers the bottom 10% but I can't get the css to work. Where am I going wrong?

```
<iframe src="http://tttdev.throughtheturnstile.com" style="width:100%; height:90%;position: absolute;" frameBorder="0"></iframe>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<div style="position: absolute; bottom:0; background-color: black; height: 50px;"></div>
```

It seems to create the div, just not style it...

Comment: This is not code review, but I have to bring up a point. Please do not use inline styles, styling every element will make it a horrible experience editing anything in the future. Instead use a linked style-sheet. Here is what I have for you though. https://codepen.io/CapySloth/pen/gRooar

Comment: Try giving it a `width: 100%` in the style for your div.  `<div style="position: absolute; bottom:0; background-color: black; height: 50px; width: 100%;"></div>
`

Comment: Im such an idiot, suggest as answer and its all yours Nicholas

Comment: @LewisSmith is `body` the container for the code above? Also, you're not floating anything so you don't need the clearing DIV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not is showing up because the div does not have a width. You can do one of two thing the make the div show up put something inside of the div or give the div a width and height. And the one that you are most likely going to need is give the div a width and height. This should work.

```
<div style="position: absolute; bottom:0; background-color: black; width: 100%; height: 50px;"></div>
```